# PowerShell logging output into multiple locations

Tags: powershell, logging

I need to write output of PowerShell `Test-Netconnection` into different folders.

I am able to write the output into a text file for one location. But I need to create text log at two different folder location.

```
$filePath = "C:\ProgramData\Prasa\Azure\Upload-Backup\networkLogFile.txt"
$filePath1 = "C:\ProgramData\Prasa\AWS\Upload-Backup\networkLogFile.txt"

Write-Output "Network Test Started: $(Get-Date)" >> $filePath
Test-NetConnection xx.xx.xx.xx -port xx -InformationLevel Detailed >> $filePath
```

I am looking for some method to include `$filePath1` so that logging should happen at both folder locations in parallel.

Comment: You're looking for [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-3.0).

Comment: Tee method worked for my requirement. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Ansgar answer, I used Tee-Object method to solve this problem.

```
Write-Output "Network Test Started: $(Get-Date)" | Tee-Object -file $filePath -Append | Out-File $filePath1 -Append
```

This method saves the log files at two different locations with append properly working.